# Editable text with fix character at the end

Tags: android

I have a edit text to input a number that represents a percentage.

I want it to show the symbol "%" after the number introduced by the user.

When the user taps 1, the editText should show "1%".
When afterwards the user taps 2, the EditText should show "12%".
And so on.

How can this be achieved?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a textchange listener and modify your text in `afterTextChanged` method , something like following , first remove the `%` , then add it again

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       editText.setText(s.getText().toString().replaceAll("%", "")+"%");
       editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length()-1) // just reset the cursor position before %
   }

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {

   }
  });
```

Comment: This will reset the cursor position after every change. You need to take care of it too.

Comment: how can I control the cursor position?

Comment: @VeneetReddy yes you are right I have edited my answer